# Using a 16 bit ADC chip with arduino

Tags: arduino-due

I need to measure voltage between 0-10 volts using my Arduino Due.  I have an ADS7805p chip, which I believe will work, but am not sure how to wire it on my breadboard.  I'm used to just using the chip on the arduino, but that only goes 0-5 volts and I can't loose the resolution by converting.  Can someone, please, point me to or instruct me on how to wire something like this to my arduino?

Comment: Why not just halve the voltage?

Comment: When you say "using the chip on the arduino", I guess you mean "directly using the analog inputs of arduino", is that correct?

Comment: The important question here is: do you absolutely need 16 bits resolution (as offered by ADS7805 ADC) or can you deal with just 10 bits, or even 12 (as supported by Arduino DUE)?

Comment: If 10 or 12 bits resolution is OK, then @Ignacio suggestion is probably the best way to follow.

Comment: I do need 16 bit resolution.

Comment: A 16-bit ADC will give you a 16-bit result, but the least significant bits won't actually be correctly representative of the signal.  You'll get better results if you can take multiple measurements and filter them (average them in the simplest case).

Comment: @ChrisStratton This tampering technique works for standard applications, low quality sensors, low quality ADCs. What if the sensor has a great dynamic range?. What if the application captures the high order modes? Removing LSB data and FIR averaging *by design* is inappropriate.

Comment: @hyprfrcb please spend some time studying signal processing theory, as your claims are exactly backwards.  Averaging doesn't *decrease* level resolution ("removing LSB data") on the contrary, provided you do not truncate your calculation, it actually *increases* resolution.  If the extra data is meaningful or not depends on if the input and conversion noise has a characteristic suitable for statistically sampling the desired signal.  Often in the real world it does to a useful extent.

Comment: "Averaging" from "extra", "statistical", "meaningful" data, only confirms that your sensors are untrustable. With high dynamic range (~120dB), low noise (~0.01% error or less) sensors, you dont need to do that. Never. And again, when interested in high frequency modes, that tampering is the worst design.

Comment: @hyprfrcb "tampering" is not a meaningful term of signal processing - that you would persistently insist on mis-using only confirms this is not a familiar subject area for you.  Bandwidth and resolution are indeed *extremely* distinct subjects.  Very few sensors actually have > 120 dB dynamic range, when they do, they push the limits of ADC technology.  But if you study deeper, you'll discover that noise of the proper character can manage to statistically sample with finer resolution than the ADC.  Keep studying - you still have a lot to learn about everyday practices in this industry!

Comment: Well, you are the one who must study indeed. And it is a shame you dont have experience and knowledge in 24 bit ADC DAQs or 120dB dyn range sensors. Good luck averaging your sensors for getting ride of the noise!

Answer (score 1):

The ADS7805 is old but still a pretty good ADC. I could imagine that you just have a few lying around that you want to use. I would simply wire it to two parallel in / serial out chips like the 74HC589 or CD4021 as used in this example:
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftIn

Start the conversion as described in Duncan C's answer and then simply clock in all 16 bits. I think you could then probably get away with 4 or 5 control lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need 16 bits of resolution then you could use that chip, but it's going to be a lot of work. Also beware that according to Mouser's website, it is not recommended for new applications. It sounds like it's being phased out/replaced.

Take a look at the data sheet linked from Mouser's website:
[ADS7805p datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/sbas020d-114025.pdf)

It has 16 bits of parallel data output, plus what sounds like 2 control lines, CS and R/(not)C (Don't know how to make the proper symbol.)

It sounds like you pull CS and R/C low to trigger a conversion, then wait for not busy to go low, switch R/C to high, then read the 16 bits of data.

To use this chip you're going to need 18 or 19 pins from your Arduino. You might want to consider a chip with a serial interface instead.

Comment: I saw that bit about not being recommended for new applications.  I'm looking around now to see if I can find a 0-10v one now.  Thanks for the thought.

Comment: The due has plenty of pins, but they are 3.3v and the ADC uses 5v logic.